# Unable to Connect to Redis (TLS) with Laravel, but TCP works fine

Tags: php, laravel, redis, phpredis

I'm using Upstash Redis with TLS connection, but I'm always getting connection lost, redis exception, timed out 2 minutes, when trying to connect to Redis. If I use `TCP`, it works fine.

Using localhost, `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, Laravel server using `php artisan serve`. Can http connect to redis over tls?

I'm following the [upstash laravel guide](https://upstash.com/blog/laravel-redis) and my config seems accurate based on laravel docs, only changes for tls is the scheme.

.env

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
# Adding tls:// infront of the redis host still gives the same connection lost error
REDIS_HOST=my-upstash-redis-84191.upstash.io
REDIS_PASSWORD=UPSTASH_REDIS_PASS
REDIS_PORT=34704
REDIS_CACHE_DB=0
```

config/database.php

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'read_write_timeout' => 60,
        ],

        'cache' => [
            // Commented out scheme when using tcp and redis connection works
            'scheme' => 'tls', 
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

Testing Redis connection API call

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

// TLS Redis gives connection lost after 2 minutes
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/redis -> RedisException Connection Lost 

// TCP Redis connects to redis and returns null, since 'test' key doesn't exist
Route::get('/redis', function () {
    // Should return null, no test key in redis
    $data = Redis::get('test');

    return [
        'redis' => $data
    ];
});
```

I used predis before and switched to phpredis as I thought that was the issue.
Since I can connect to redis with tcp, just not tls. Are there special instructions and values needed beyond the `scheme = tls` to get redis working?

## Versions

```
"php": "^8.2.0",
"laravel/framework": "^10.0",

PHPRedis: 5.3.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing the same error using upstash and phpredis. If I do not use the TLS, I can connect just fine. The error only persists when I am using the TLS. Have you found any solution?

Edit:
I solved this by prepending `tlsv1.2://` to `REDIS_HOST` key in the `.env` file and removing the `'scheme' => 'tls'` from the `config/database.php` file.

Comment: That sounds like a bug from laravel's side, adding `scheme => tls` should preappend that tls statement.